# Getting links from markdown file even if link is in the link text

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, string-matching

I've got a markdown file with some links in it. I try to grab all these links with their corresponding link text. It works fine with simple links but I can't figure out how to match a link with an image link.

If I have an image link like `[![alt text](https://example.com/image.svg)](https://other-example.com)`, I'd like to grab both links and both link texts.

I came up with two regexes:

- `/\[([^\]!]+)]\((https:\/\/[^\)]+)\)/gi`
- `/\[([^\[!]+)](\(https:\/\/[^\)]+\))/gi`

```js
let str = `# Title with Image [![alt text](https://example.com/image.svg)](https://other-example.com)

## Links

- [First](https://somesite.com/path/to-page) - voluptates explicabo debitis aspernatur dolor, qui dolores.
- [Second](https://example.io/this/is/page) - molestiae animi eius nisi quam quae quisquam beatae reiciendis.`

let regex1 = /\[([^\]!]+)]\((https:\/\/[^\)]+)\)/gi
let regex2 = /\[([^\[!]+)](\(https:\/\/[^\)]+\))/gi
let links1 = [...str.matchAll(regex1)].map((m) => ({ text: m[1], link: m[2] }))
let links2 = [...str.matchAll(regex2)].map((m) => ({ text: m[1], link: m[2] }))

console.log(links1)
console.log(links2)
```

The expected result would be (order doesn't matter):

```json
[
  {
    "text": "![alt text](https://example.com/image.svg)",
    "link": "https://other-example.com"
  },
  {
    "text": "alt text",
    "link": "https://example.com/image.svg"
  },
  {
    "text": "First",
    "link": "https://somesite.com/path/to-page"
  },
  {
    "text": "Second",
    "link": "https://example.io/this/is/page"
  }
]
```

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/QI5Hup/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([^\]!]+)` blocks you from matching the `![alt text](https://example.com/image.svg)`, so I replaced it with `(!\[.+?\]\(.+?\)|.+?)` that first looks for `![alt text](https://example.com/image.svg)` and then `alt text` as a text wrapped in `[]` (square braces).

```
/(?=\[(!\[.+?\]\(.+?\)|.+?)]\((https:\/\/[^\)]+)\))/gi
```

Note, for cross-matching, you should wrap the pattern into positive lookahead. Also, see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dv1C7j/1).

```js
let str = `# Title with Image [![alt text](https://example.com/image.svg)](https://other-example.com)

## Links

- [First](https://somesite.com/path/to-page) - voluptates explicabo debitis aspernatur dolor, qui dolores.
- [Second](https://example.io/this/is/page) - molestiae animi eius nisi quam quae quisquam beatae reiciendis.`

let regex = /(?=\[(!\[.+?\]\(.+?\)|.+?)]\((https:\/\/[^\)]+)\))/gi

let links = [...str.matchAll(regex)].map((m) => ({ text: m[1], link: m[2] }))

console.log(links)
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working as expected.